# Several unintended lines when attempting to create voronoi diagram given scatter point locations

Tags: python, numpy, voronoi

[image]I'm trying to create a Voronoi diagram given a set of scatterplot points. However, several "extra unintended lines" appear to get calculated in the process. Some of these "extra" lines appear to be the infinite edges getting incorrectly calculated. But others are appearing randomly in the middle of the plot as well. How can I **only** create an extra edge when it's needed/required to connect a polygon to the edge of the plot (e.g. plot boundaries)?

My graph outer boundaries are:

```
boundaries = np.array([[0, -2], [0, 69], [105, 69], [105, -2], [0, -2]])
```

Here's the section dealing with the voronoi diagram creation:

```
def voronoi_polygons(voronoi, diameter):

    centroid = voronoi.points.mean(axis=0)
    ridge_direction = defaultdict(list)
    for (p, q), rv in zip(voronoi.ridge_points, voronoi.ridge_vertices):
        u, v = sorted(rv)
        if u == -1:
            t = voronoi.points[q] - voronoi.points[p]  # tangent
            n = np.array([-t[1], t[0]]) / np.linalg.norm(t)  # normal
            midpoint = voronoi.points[[p, q]].mean(axis=0)
            direction = np.sign(np.dot(midpoint - centroid, n)) * n
            ridge_direction[p, v].append(direction)
            ridge_direction[q, v].append(direction)

    for i, r in enumerate(voronoi.point_region):
        region = voronoi.regions[r]
        if -1 not in region:
            # Finite region.
            yield Polygon(voronoi.vertices[region])
            continue
        # Infinite region.
        inf = region.index(-1)  # Index of vertex at infinity.
        j = region[(inf - 1) % len(region)]  # Index of previous vertex.
        k = region[(inf + 1) % len(region)]  # Index of next vertex.
        if j == k:
            # Region has one Voronoi vertex with two ridges.
            dir_j, dir_k = ridge_direction[i, j]
        else:
            # Region has two Voronoi vertices, each with one ridge.
            dir_j, = ridge_direction[i, j]
            dir_k, = ridge_direction[i, k]

        # Length of ridges needed for the extra edge to lie at least
        # 'diameter' away from all Voronoi vertices.
        length = 2 * diameter / np.linalg.norm(dir_j + dir_k)

        # Polygon consists of finite part plus an extra edge.
        finite_part = voronoi.vertices[region[inf + 1:] + region[:inf]]
        extra_edge = [voronoi.vertices[j] + dir_j * length,
                      voronoi.vertices[k] + dir_k * length]
        combined_finite_edge = np.concatenate((finite_part, extra_edge))
        poly = Polygon(combined_finite_edge)
        yield poly
```

Here are the points being used:

```
 ['52.629' '24.28099822998047']
 ['68.425' '46.077999114990234']
 ['60.409' '36.7140007019043']
 ['72.442' '28.762001037597656']
 ['52.993' '43.51799964904785']
 ['59.924' '16.972000122070312']
 ['61.101' '55.74899959564209']
 ['68.9' '13.248001098632812']
 ['61.323' '29.0260009765625']
 ['45.283' '36.97500038146973']
 ['52.425' '19.132999420166016']
 ['37.739' '28.042999267578125']
 ['48.972' '2.3539962768554688']
 ['33.865' '30.240001678466797']
 ['52.34' '64.94799995422363']
 ['52.394' '45.391000747680664']
 ['52.458' '34.79800033569336']
 ['31.353' '43.14500045776367']
 ['38.194' '39.24399948120117']
 ['98.745' '32.15999984741211']
 ['6.197' '32.606998443603516']
```

Answer (score 1):

Figured out what was wrong: after each polygon I needed to add a null x and y value or else it would attempt to 'stitch' one polygon to another, drawing an additional unintended line in order to do so. So the data should really look more like this:

```
GameTime,Half,ObjectType,JerseyNumber,X,Y,PlayerIDEvent,PlayerIDTracking,MatchIDEvent,Position,teamId,i_order,v_vor_x,v_vor_y
0.0,1,1,22,None,None,578478,794888,2257663,3,35179.0,0,22.79645297,6.20866756
0.0,1,1,22,None,None,578478,794888,2257663,3,35179.0,1,17.63464264,3.41230187
0.0,1,1,22,None,None,578478,794888,2257663,3,35179.0,2,20.27639318,34.29191902
0.0,1,1,22,None,None,578478,794888,2257663,3,35179.0,3,32.15600546,36.60432421
0.0,1,1,22,None,None,578478,794888,2257663,3,35179.0,4,38.34639812,33.62806739
0.0,1,1,22,None,None,578478,794888,2257663,3,35179.0,5,22.79645297,6.20866756
0.0,1,1,22,None,None,578478,794888,2257663,3,35179.0,5,nan,nan
0.0,1,1,22,33.865,30.240001678466797,578478,794888,2257663,3,35179.0,,,
0.0,1,0,92,None,None,369351,561593,2257663,1,32446.0,0,46.91696938,29.44801535
0.0,1,0,92,None,None,369351,561593,2257663,1,32446.0,1,55.37574848,29.5855499
0.0,1,0,92,None,None,369351,561593,2257663,1,32446.0,2,58.85876401,23.20381766
0.0,1,0,92,None,None,369351,561593,2257663,1,32446.0,3,57.17455086,21.5228301
0.0,1,0,92,None,None,369351,561593,2257663,1,32446.0,4,44.14237744,22.03925667
0.0,1,0,92,None,None,369351,561593,2257663,1,32446.0,5,45.85962774,28.83613332
0.0,1,0,92,None,None,369351,561593,2257663,1,32446.0,5,nan,nan
0.0,1,0,92,52.629,24.28099822998047,369351,561593,2257663,1,32446.0,,,
0.0,1,0,27,None,None,704169,704169,2257663,2,32446.0,0,65.56965667,33.4292025
0.0,1,0,27,None,None,704169,704169,2257663,2,32446.0,1,57.23303682,32.43809027
0.0,1,0,27,None,None,704169,704169,2257663,2,32446.0,2,55.65704152,38.97814049
0.0,1,0,27,None,None,704169,704169,2257663,2,32446.0,3,60.75304149,44.53251169
0.0,1,0,27,None,None,704169,704169,2257663,2,32446.0,4,65.14170295,40.77562188
0.0,1,0,27,None,None,704169,704169,2257663,2,32446.0,5,65.56965667,33.4292025
0.0,1,0,27,None,None,704169,704169,2257663,2,32446.0,5,nan,nan
```

Answer (score 0):

Most likely this is due to the errors associated with floating point arithmetic while computing the voronoi traingulation from your data (esp. the second column).

Assuming that, there is no single solution for such kinds of problems. I urge you to go through [this page](http://www.qhull.org/html/qh-impre.htm#prec)* of the Qhull manual and try iterating through those parameters in [`qhull_options`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.Voronoi.html) before generating the `voronoi` object that you are inputting in the function. An example would be `qhull_options='Qbb Qc Qz QJ'`.

Other than that I doubt there is anything that could be modified in the function to avoid such a problem.

*This will take some time though. Just be patient.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! Appreciate you taking the time to respond.